# Limit of an expression

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^n\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{k!}|n-k|=\sqrt{2/\pi}$$
Is this limit true? I should show limit is true. It is allowed to use computer programs to find this limit.
Thanks for your helps...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has a nice probabilistic interpretation. Given that $X$ is a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with parameter $\lambda=n$, we are essentially computing the expected value of the absolute difference between $X$ and its mean $n$. [The central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) gives that $Y\sim N(n,n)$ (a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean and variance equal to $n$) is an excellent approximation of our distribution for large values of $n$, hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{e^n \sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{n^k}{k!}|n-k|&\approx&\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x-n|\exp\left(-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2n}\right)\,dx\\&=&\frac{2}{n\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2n}\right)\,dx\\&=&\color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}},\end{eqnarray*}$$
so the limit **is not** zero.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I will use it in my study. Any problem?

Comment: @guest: not at all, you are welcome.

Comment: Pedantry, but I think it might be more usual to write $Y \sim N(n,n)$, i.e. in terms of the mean and variance $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.  This does not affect the rest of your answer.

Comment: @Henry: yes, there is an ambiguity in defining the standard parameters for a normal distribution, both $N(\mu,\sigma)$ and $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ are used. Anyway, I wrote down the pdf.

Comment: I have no knowledge about distributions but it will help me in limit calculations. I want to learn more about distributions. By the way, in fact I have another limit to be calculated.

Comment: It is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}|\ln n-\ln k|\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=?$

Comment: @guest: better to post it in another question. It is quite different from the limit solved here.

Comment: It seems like geometric distribution when $p=\frac{1}{n}$. But I have no idea about how to find expected value in geometric distribution?

Comment: @guest: there is a geometric series in disguise and the limit can be computed by using a Riemann sums argument.

Comment: ok ı will ask it as another question.

Comment: I added the question with title "limit of the expression "

Answer (score 10):

Split the series at $k = n$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}\lvert n-k\rvert &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}(n-k) + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}(k-n)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^k}{(k-1)!} + \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{(k-1)!} - \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} + \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!} - \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n^{k+1}}{k!}\\
&= 2\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!}.
\end{align}

So you are looking for

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{n!e^n}.$$

Now recall or look up Stirling's formula.

Comment: (+1) We got the same result using two very different approaches. However, yours is way more elegant, I did not notice the hidden telescopic sum.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I will use it in my study. Any problem?

Comment: @guest Happy to help. I don't understand the last part, though, any problem with what?

Comment: @guest Oh, that's okay.